# Creating word list from document

Tags: text-processing, words

I'm trying to find an efficient way of learning vocabulary in new languages. I'd like to be able to create word lists using files that contain books.
I'm new to Linux, any help much appreciated.

I would like to:

- have a command that will take as input a text file (txt format for example) and output another file that contains a list of all individual words in the first file.
- The new file should be ordered alphabetically and contain no duplicates (each word should be included only once.)
- Ideally, the command should also be able to check against a second file and avoid repeating any words contained in that file. (So that I can create a file or words I already know and that are not repeated.)

Is there a suitable command to do this?

Comment: Capitalization, punctuation, plurals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a "word" as a sequence of ["word-constituent characters"](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators) (commonly defined as letters, numbers, and/or underscores) then you can do what you want using GNU `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk -v RS='\\W+' 'ARGIND==1{arr[$0]; next} !($0 in arr)' skip file | sort -u
```

where `skip` is your file of words you don't want printed and `file` contains your book.

`\W` is just shorthand for `[^[:alnum:]_]`. If your definition of "word" excludes digits, though, then change `RS='\\W+'` to `RS='[^[:alpha:]_]+'`, or if it includes apostrophes and hyphens then change it to `RS="[^[:alpha:]_'-]+"`, or change `RS` to whatever else matches the negation of your definition of the set of characters you consider as making up "words".

To learn awk get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: I'm without speech! Works like a charm. Thank you so so much. Turns out there are 14000 distinct words in the divine comedy (counting conjugations).

Comment: You're welcome. Give it a few hours to see if you get a better answer and then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.